# Почему функция не видит подфункцию в JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ооп, функции, prototype

Прочел [эту](https://learn.javascript.ru/classes) статью и не могу понять почему не работает:

```
function test() {
    this.nameBRO = '123';
    this.speedBRO = 555;
}

test.prototype.goodBRO = function(a) {
    this.str = a;
    console.log(this.str);
};
```

Собственно 
`test.nameBRO` вызвать не могу, пишет Uncaught TypeError:

```
test.nameBRO is not a function
```

Тоже самое и `speedBRO`.

Что касается `goodBRO : test.goodBRO('fd')` - так не вызывается, только если писать `test.prototype.goodBRO('fd')`.

Что я делаю не так, тут же все просто как 5 копеек, почему не работает?

Comment: `goodBRO : (new test()).goodBRO('fd')`, только у Вас `goodBRO` ничего не возвращает

Answer (score 1):

Есть два способа определить метод класса (в посте подфункция), функциональный и прототипный.

В функциональном, при создании класса явно указаны его методы:

```
function test() { //имя класса
    this.nameBRO = '123'; //свойство класса
    this.speedBRO = 555;
    this.goodBRO = function(a) { // метод класса
        this.str = a;
        console.log(this.str);
    }
}
```

В таком случае новый объект

```
t = new test()
```

выглядит так

Object { nameBRO: "123", speedBRO: 555, goodBRO: test/this.goodBRO() }

В прототипном метод назначается не классу, а его прототипу, родителю.

```
function test() { //имя класса
    this.nameBRO = '123'; //свойство класса
    this.speedBRO = 555;
}
test.prototype.goodBRO = function(a) { // метод класса
    this.str = a;
    console.log(this.str);
};
```

В таком случае обьект выглядит так 
Object { nameBRO: "123", speedBRO: 555 }

Но метод вызывается в обоих случаях одинаково:

```
t = new test()
t.goodBRO(12);
```

Comment: добавь описание, что именно происходит в ответе